# Use application properties from additonal file beside application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, application.properties

I am not talking about profiles feature in `application.properties`. I have `local.properties` file which is loaded to `ZooKeeperPropertySource` and I want properties which are there, to be treated like the ones set in `application.properties` and still be able to use `application.properties`.

I have found one solution: `spring.config.location` which enables to set multiple sources so I would set default `application.properties` as first source and `local.properties` as second source. But I don't want to it by passing environent variable, I want to do it in code/config. Are there any additional ways of achieving that? Ideally, I would like to use properties from `ZooKeeperPropertySource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change Spring Boot startup defaults in your Spring Boot Application class. For example, also look for `local.properties` files:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new 
    SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .properties("spring.config.name:application,local")
            .build()
            .run(args);
}
```

You do need to modify the `spring.config.name` property, otherwise it will only look for `application.properties` files.